# Serenity+jbehave : How to pass test data from external resources

Tags: serenity-bdd

I am using Jbehave and serenity in my BDDs.My requirement is "Passing test data from excel sheet".How do I get the test data from excel in my Given when and then?
I tried with injecting the test data to a test step,

```
withTestDataFrom( filePath ).run( testSteps ).givenStatement( #param1,#param2 );
```

But that wont satisfies my requirement. Is there any other way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

you can use Apache POI just like java code. refe this [link](https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#Iterator) and [this](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/java-read-write-excel-file-apache-poi/).

you can also try the below code for any other external input cases.
you can use the properties file like [this](http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-properties-file-examples/).

you can also use the JBehave table parameter just like [this](http://jbehave.org/reference/stable/parametrised-scenarios.html).

Comment: Thanks for the reply,                                                                                 But i need my input data(In my case Excel will be input) to be passed from example and iterate through the file for each row execute given ,when and then.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

1. put the pipe ("|") delimited rows into `src\test\resources\data\data.table`
2. in `build.gradle`, put

   ```
   sourceSets {
     main {
       java {
         srcDirs = ['src/main/java']
       }
     }
     test {
       java {
         srcDirs = ['src/test/java']
       }
       resources {
         srcDirs = ['src/test/resources']
       }
     }
   }
   ```
3. in the `.story` file, write:

   ```
   Examples:
   data\data.table
   ```